# How LaTeX removes "CHAPTER 1. NAME" from header of Introduction chapter?

Tags: header-footer, tocloft, titletoc

I use:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
```

When table of contents was in the beginning of the book it seemed working well, on the header of Introduction was INTRODUCTION with page number, on other chapters' headers CHAPTER 1. CHAPTERNAME.
Now I mooved table of contents to the end of the book and I have CHAPTER 0. INTRODUCTION and I can't fix it.

UPD: Here is my header code.
\documentclass[russian,11pt,a5paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext, color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

```
\usepackage[a5paper,tmargin=2.5cm,inner=1.5cm,outer=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[pagestyles,newlinetospace,newparttoc]{titlesec}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}
\graphicspath{{./images}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering} 
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{0pt} 
{\normalfont\large\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{40pt}{30pt}
\def\clearpage{\par}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=it}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=it}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\chaptertitle\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large}
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.8cm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\large} 
\sloppy
```

Comment: you need to show a small complete document with the problem. Neither `\chapter` nor `\chaptermark` are defined by latex but are defined by the document class, so impossible to guess an answer just using the fragment you have shown